# script js dentro do php

Tags: php, javascript

**1º Código** :

```
$urlExclusao  = "index.php?".PARAMETER_NAME_ACTION."=delete&";
$urlExclusao .= PARAMETER_NAME_FILE."=noticia";
$urlExclusao .= "&id=".$row->noticiaid;

$test = $urlExclusao;
echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function confirmation() {
    var answer = confirm('Deseja excluir essa Noticia ?');
    if (answer = true){
        window.location.href = ". $test ";
    }
   }
</script>";
```

**2º Código** :

`<a onclick=\"confirmation()\"><img src=\"".DIR_ICONS."delete.png\" title=\"Excluir\" /></a>";`

No 1º código estou tentando mostrar um `confirm` na tela para perguntar se realmente o usuário ira querer excluir essa notícia.

No 2º código tem um link com um `onclick` para a função em JavaScript.

O problema é o seguinte ao clicar no link de excluir ele simplesmente não mostrar a janela de confirmação nem nada, é como se não houvesse link algum.

Comment: Adicione o código em texto, não dá pra simular o problema em um código de uma imagem, facilita ter o mesmo em texto.

Comment: Tranquilo ! Obrigado, pela dica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No onClick, é necessário você passar a chamada da função e não a referência a ela. Ou seja, precisa ter abertura e fechamento de parenteses após o nome da função "confirmation".

```js
function confirmation(){
  location.href = confirm("Deseja ir para o site do google") ? "http://www.google.com.br" : '';
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="confirmation()"> Ir para o google </a>
```

Comment: Não funcionou, o cursor do mouse mudou para `default` e tbm n funciona

Comment: Fiz um exemplo funcionando. Por favor verifique no inspecionador de elementos do seu navegador se o seu script foi realmente inserido na página